# Ubuntu 11.04 Ruby on Rails install write permissions error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

I am trying to install rails and have installed rvm and am trying to install rails but it is saying I do not have write permissions.

```
$ gem install rails --version 3.0.7
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.8 directory.
```

When I try sudo it give me this error, I know that you can use --no-ri --no-r-doc but even when I did this rails was not installed properly. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$ sudo gem install rails --version 3.0.7
Successfully installed rails-3.0.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.7...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.7...
file 'lib' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from my experience with rvm, gems should't stay in /var/lib/

if you didn't specifically asked for this, there might be a problem with your rvm installation

if so, i would definetly recommend a clean rvm install by following [ryan bigg's guide of installing rvm](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you). i followed it every time and never ever had the slightest problem after.

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I actually was looking at this guide earlier but passed on it for some reason.